# How to do the WHERE clause on a UPDATE statement that uses a JOIN?

Tags: mysql

In this example the field username is inside the users table and the field email is in the profiles table.

```
UPDATE `profiles`
JOIN `users` ".
SET `username` = 'foo',
`email` = 'bar@aol.com'
WHERE users.user_id = '1'
```

In this where clause I am using users.user_id, but this causes all fields in the profile table to be updated with the email "bar@aol.com". What is the syntax to specify profiles.user_id in addition to the users.user_id in the WHERE clause?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to join the tables like this:

```
UPDATE `profiles`
JOIN `users` on profiles.user_id = users.user_id
SET `username` = 'foo',
`email` = 'bar@aol.com'
WHERE users.user_id = '1'
```

Comment: I found out at 10.1.36-MariaDB, I have to add table name in all the conditions at the where clause, in this case it is the table 'users'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Update profiles,users set profiles.username='foo',profiles.email_id='foo@foo.com'
where profiles.user_id=users.user_id and users.user_id=1
```